# Boost::filesystem::is_empty() returns false for Symlinks

Tags: c++, windows, boost, symlink, boost-filesystem

I've been using Boost 1.46.1 in my project until a week ago. After upgrading everything to Boost 1.55.0 I noticed that some functionality is not working as before.

My software loads configuration files which are placed via SymLinks. I'm using Microsofts [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to do this.

I today found out that while `boost::filesystem::is_empty()` in version 1.46.1 was returning `false` for my links, it now returns `true` in 1.55.0. Unfortunately I'm not able to change the component which uses that code. The result is that my config files aren't loaded anymore.

- Is there a way to create links in a way that Boost is able to recognize them?
- If I get access to the code: How would I need to change it to work again?

**UPDATE:**

Some more information in response to the comments:

- The SymLink is valid, there is a file linked to it
- The file linked to the SymLink is not empty, it is a valid config file which worked before
- The user has permissions to the SymLink and to the linked file
- I'm able to do an `fopen` on that file and read its contents

**UPDATE2:**

I just created a Github project with everything included to recreate the issue. I used VS 2013 Express to compile the program:

- [GitHub Project - BoostSymLinkError](https://github.com/monsdar/BoostSymLinkError)
- [main.cpp](https://github.com/monsdar/BoostSymLinkError/blob/master/main.cpp)

Comment: Sounds very strange. One has to do extra work to detect a symlink as such. Can you post example code.

Comment: Please provide detail on exactly what is the status of the symlink you are passing to Boost.  Is the link broken (target does not exist)?  If the target exists, does it have 0 size (target is empty)?  Or does the symlink lead to a non-empty file?  Also make sure the user has permission to both the symlink and its target.

Comment: I just confirmed that boost 5.5.0's as used with mingw g++ 4.8.2 reports `is_empty` as true for link to non-empty file.

Comment: Just added more information, thanks for the comments so far

Comment: Just created an example project, see the above update for the links.

Comment: I tested Boost 1.55 on Mac OS and it reports is_empty() as false if the symlink points to a non-empty file, and true if it points to an empty file.  So it "follows" the symlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that older versions of Boost filesystem (V2) on Windows used VC++'s `stat()` function to obtain the information on the target file, and that function followed symlinks.

Newer versions of the filesystem library (V3) use the  the Win32 `GetFileAttributesExW()` API, and it doesn't follow symlinks, so the size of the object specified by the path gets returned as 0.

[It looks like](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) filesystem V3 was made the default in Boost 1.46 and V2 was removed from the library in 1.48. One possible fix for your problem is to move back to a version of Boost before 1.48 (and possibly build the libraries with the `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION` macro set to 2).

I have opened a bug against this and the bug report includes a patch against `libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp` that fixes the problem:

- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9824

Keep in mind that the patch I submitted in the bug report hasn't had much testing (for example, it needs to be tested against other versions of Windows, with the MinGW toolchain, with paths that include characters outside the ASCII range, directories as targets, and probably a number of other things I haven't thought of). However, if you want to continue using a recent Boost release, you're welcome to patch your local Boost libs to see if it solves the problem for you.

Comment: Should have mentioned that: I already opened a bugticket: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9816 Sorry for that. Good explanation of the issue, thanks for the patch!